# Find location of slice in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have an ndarray subclass which implements loading/saving of one or more records into a flat binary file. After the records are loaded, I can access them in the normal NumPy fashion.

My question is about what happens when I slice the result (or indeed, any NumPy array). This normally produces a 'view' ie. an array that refers to the same buffer as the parent array.

Once I have this view, is there any way to determine the position of the view V in the array A? More precisely, I would like to know the byte offset (from the start of A's data buffer) at which V begins. This would allow me to write the slice back onto disk at the right offset.

**Here's some example code to show the situation**:

```
# Imagine a as consisting of 4 4-byte records...
a = np.arange(16, dtype='B').reshape(4,4)

# I select the first record
v = a[0]

print (v)

# [0 1 2 3]

# I can determine that v is a subarray:

is_subarray = v.base != None

# I can determine which dimension the slice spans..

whichdim = v.base.strides.index (v.strides[-1])

# But not its position along that dimension.
```

Comment: Why don't you store the information you need (dim + index) along the view in a custom class ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbey Sure, I could do that... OTOH NumPy knows the location of that slice already. It seems silly to duplicate that information (isn't there some way of getting that info from NumPy?)

Comment: Aren't memmaps more useful to you anyways? Sure its possible to get it... But nicely, not sure.

Comment: @Sebastian Memmaps are good, but they currently have a few problems that makes me want to stay away from them. The main one is that array subclass can't be guaranteed to be preserved, because a[0]['x'] and a['x'][0] do not both return a conventional array (one of them returns a 'numpy.void', the end result is inconsistent behaviour WRT returning scalar values). This has been the source of much frustration. I want to subclass something that behaves itself (like ndarray)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The informaiton is exposed through `array.__array_interface__` (maybe somewhere better too), however I think you should probably just use memmaps to begin with and not mess around with this. Check for example the numpy code to the `np.may_share_memory` function (or actually `np.byte_bounds`).

Comment: Thank you!!!! Especially for giving such a detailed answer... Believe me, I wish I could continue to use memmaps. I've given them quite a long try (years) cause I thought they were the thing to use here, and like I said.. they're nice when they work, and bewildering when they don't. I'll give this a go instead.

Comment: Actually, `np.byte_bounds` is ideal . `np.byte_bounds(V)[0] - np.byte_bounds(V.base)[0]` gives the byte offset of V into A, which can be easily converted into record-based offset by inspecting itemsize and shape.

Comment: A small warning though. In different numpy versions `ndarray.base` may point to different arrays if you make a view based on a view. IE. you may have to do `.base` multiple times to get to the original I believe (I think this may change in the next versions to always point directly to the original).

Comment: yes, that seems to be the case in 1.6.2, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: @kampu what was your problem with memmaps? They propagate oddly (x+x gives a new memmap but it actually isn't one), but I think there is a simple fix for that if thats one of your issues?

Comment: Well to be precise, it's actually a problem related to memmap recordarrays; in some circumstances -- arr['fieldname'][index] IIRC, a numpy.void will be returned instead of an appropriate ndarray subclass, so certain key features will not be available.

Comment: anyway, since the time I asked this question, I also realized that memmaps are inappropriate for the application as mostly I want to save data at a fixed time, not whenever it is changed. An example of the kind of situation this is intended for is, a file containing fixed length records, sets of 8 x (50x50) images, which I want to load as a single set, but allow any contiguous slice of that (8, 50, 50) shaped array to be saved individually.